# Integration of Telerik.web.UI dll

Tags: .net, telerik

Can Somebody tell me how can i put reference new version  telerik.web.ui dll without with removing the old reference of telerik.web.ui .

Because don't want to migration old controls to new controls

Comment: tell more about your project. Do you want to have some parts of the project using old controls and other parts using new controls and both old and new are inside a dll with same name?

Comment: My asp.net application in net 2.0 and having dll telerik.web.UI and it's version is 2009 and i want put latest version of telerik.web.ui

Comment: I want put both dll in my application but names of dll's are  same and when i remove reference of pol dll and put new dll in project it prompt me to change version of project and change the version of system.web.extension which has version 1.0.61025.0 when i change asp.net version of my application from 2.0 to 4.0 in iis application work some of the older features not workoing like radajaxmanager for partial postback work but loading panel doesn't work.Please tell me way how i handle this situation.Can put both in same project so that migration of controls cann't take place. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not a common way of doing things, cause what would be the need of updating the Telerik.web.UI if you don't want to use the new controls ?!

Anyway you should be able to achieve it, by doing the following:

- Add the reference to both the dlls in your client application solution.
- Then in the Solution Explorer under the reference node select either the old or new version class library.
- In the property window change Aliases field from global to your custom value like "oldVer" if you are updating the old version.
- Make similar change after selecting the other reference node class library as well.
- Then access code using the following snippet style

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(oldVer::MyLibrary.MyClass.method());
  Console.WriteLine(newVer::MyLibrary.MyClass.method());
  ```

Good luck then ;)